# Como fazer casting entre classes base e derivadas?

Tags: c++

Eu tenho um exercício que diz que eu tenho que criar uma base. Essa base tem duas derivadas. Eu tenho que fazer um cast da classe derivada(1) para a classe derivada(2) e da classe derivada(2) para a classe base. Como eu devo fazer um exercício como este **sem utilizar referências**?

Comment: O exercício está confuso, mal-formulado. O casting de uma classe-filha para uma classe-mãe é feito automaticamente.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos diga isso para o meu professor :/ pensei a mesma coisa!

Comment: Creio que a única forma é entrar em contato com ele e pedir para explicar melhor o que ele quer. Aí você atualiza a pergunta aqui.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Haha... Ele acabou de me mandar um e-mail falando que o exercício seria clarificado; metade dos alunos reportaram a dificuldade para ele!

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Editei a questão, mas removi o meu código, pois agora quero apenas aprender!

Comment: Continua sem fazesr nenhum sentido, porque não existe relação alguma entre `derivada1` e `derivada2`. Elas podem ser consideradas do mesmo supertipo, mas não existe conversão entre uma e outra. Esse exercício basicamente pede pra você estender uma classe `Fruta` com `Banana` e `Maçã` e transformar uma banana numa maçã. Professores e suas ideias mirabolantes --'

Answer (score 3):

Isto pode mostrar o uso de um cast para uma classe base:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    void metodoHerdado(){

        std::cout << "Metodo na base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derivada : public Base{
public:
    void metodoHerdado(){

        std::cout << "Metodo na derivada" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    Base* ponteiroBase = new Derivada;

    Derivada* ponteiroDerivada = static_cast<Derivada*>(ponteiroBase);

    ponteiroBase->metodoHerdado();
    ponteiroDerivada->metodoHerdado();

    return 0;
}
```

O exemplo basicamente mostra que podemos criar uma instancia a partir de uma classe derivada e "armazená-la" em um ponteiro para a clase base, porém os métodos não virtuais chamados a partir deste ponteiro ocasionarão a execução dos métodos definidos na clase base. Caso seja necessário chamar um método redefinido na classe derivada neste caso, você precisará fazer um cast para que o ponteiro passe a ser reconhecido como sendo para a classe derivada.

Para uma classe irmã, preciso pensar melhor em uma justificativa =)

Comment: Se puder colocar mais texto explicando a resposta seria excelenete!

Comment: O exemplo basicamente mostra que podemos criar uma instancia a partir de uma classe derivada e "armazená-la" em um ponteiro para a clase base, porém os métodos não virtuais chamados a partir deste ponteiro ocasionarão a execução dos métodos definidos na clase base. Caso seja necessário chamar um método redefinido na classe derivada neste caso, você precisará fazer um cast para que o ponteiro passe a ser reconhecido como sendo para a classe derivada.