# Como montar uma coleção de Objetos derivados, e utilizar funções especificas de cada um?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo, map

Eu quero criar uma lista dinâmica que contem todos os objetos derivados de Componente.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
map<string, Componente> tabuleiro_componentes;
tabuleiro_componentes.insert(make_pair('000',Peca(//Parametros)));
tabuleiro_componentes.insert(make_pair('001',Escudeiro(//Parametros)));
```

Com esse código eu consigo adicionar os componentes ao Map, ele entende que as classes são filhas de Componente. O que eu quero fazer é buscar no map pela string e utilizar os metodos exclusivos de **Peca** e **Escudeiro**, só que as únicas opções mostradas são os métodos do **Componente**.

Acredito que seja pelo fato do Map estar como `<string, Componente>`, devo tentar outra abordagem ou existe solução ?

**Solução:** Construí uma solução paliativa utilizando ponteiros simples e dinamic_cast:
https://github.com/KaueAlves/Grimorie-Tabuleiro/tree/kaue-dev-dinamic_cast

O arquivo **componente.h**:

```
#ifndef COMPONENTE_H
#define COMPONENTE_H

#include "Default.h"
#include "Posicao.h"

class Componente
{
protected:
    int id;
    Posicao pos;
    string nome;
    string tipo;
public:
    Componente(/* args */);
    ~Componente();
    Componente(int id, string nome, string tipo);
    // Gets
    Posicao getPosicao();
    string getTipo();
    string getNome();
    int getID();
    // Sets 
    void setNome(string nome);
    void setID(int id);
};


#endif
```

O arquivo **Peca.h**:

```
#ifndef PECA_H
#define PECA_H

#include "default.h"
#include "Posicao.h"
#include "Componente.h"

using namespace std;

class Peca : public Componente
{
private:
    string sinal;
    Posicao pos;
    // Cor cor;
    int qntMovimentos, qntMaxMovimentos;
    pair<int,int> tamanho;
public:
    //Construtor - Destruidor
    Peca();
    Peca( Posicao pos, pair<int,int> tamanho);
    ~Peca();

    //Gets
    Posicao getPosicao();
    int getQntMaxMovimetnos();
    int getQntMovimentos();
    pair<int,int> getTamanho();
    string getSinal();

    //Sets
    void setPosicao(Posicao pos);
    void setQntMaxMovimentos(int qntMaxMovimentos);
    void setQntMovimentos(int qntMovimentos);
    void setTamanho(pair<int,int> tamanho);
    void setSinal(string sinal);

    //Funções
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

O arquivo **Escudeiro.h**:

```
#ifndef Escudeiro_H
#define Escudeiro_H

#include "../Default.h"
#include "../Peca.h"

class Escudeiro : public Peca
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    Escudeiro();
    ~Escudeiro();
    Escudeiro(Posicao pos, pair<int,int> tamanho);
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro erro é que está guardando objetos de um tipo em outro tipo, isso não dá o resultado que espera. Se você reserva espaço para um tipo `Componente` e depois coloca um objeto `Peca` que tem um tamanho maior, como espera que caiba o objeto ali? Você está corrompendo a memória e nem sabe. A solução para isso é fazer uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Usando um ponteiro você garante que todo objeto na estrutura seja do mesmo tamanho, o tamanho de um ponteiro e o objeto com o dado em si esteja em outro lugar. Feito isto é possível trabalhar com objetos diferentes.

Mas ainda tem um problema quando pega o objeto. Você precisa fazer um *cast*. Quando pega um elemento diretamente de uma estrutura de `Componente`s esse objeto será um `Componente`, portanto ele só pode acessar os membros deste tipo. Como você sabe que ele pode ser algo mais específico você pode indicar para o compilador enxergá-lo como esse objeto específico e aí os membros que deseja estarão disponíveis. Mas tem um problema: você vai transformar em qual tipo? Existem objetos de tipos diferentes dentro desse mapa, você só pode transformá-lo se tiver certeza que ele é do tipo em questão, caso contrário dará erro.

Veja [Qual tipo de ponteiro inteligente escolher?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248539/101). E procure por outras perguntas sobre o assunto. E [Como fazer casting entre classes base e derivadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7906/101).